# Is this claim true that $g\circ h$ is bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Please help me to probe the truth of the following statement.

> if $g:Y \to Z$ , $h:X \to Y$ and  $g\circ h$ is bijection $\Rightarrow$ $g$ and $h$ are bijection too.

Comment: This is the third question you've asked in the past hour on bijections, all of which show zero effort on your part. I strongly suggest that you review the other answers given and provide some work so that we can help you understand this stuff, instead of just doing your homework for you.

Comment: @P.. Do you think flash meant to denote $h$ as $h: z\to x$?

Comment: You can have left/right-invertible functions. This isn't true in any case. For example, consider $$g\circ h = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $g:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, neither of which are bijective. Their composition is the identity on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Similar question: [Example where $f\circ g$ is bijective, but neither $f$ nor $g$ is bijective](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198379/example-where-f-circ-g-is-bijective-but-neither-f-nor-g-is-bijective).

Comment: You have tagged your question [tag:linear-algebra]. If you want examples of *linear maps* with these properties, you should mention it in the post. If not, [tag:elementary-set-theory] and [tag:functions] would be better tags for your question.

Comment: @faranak50:$\Large\color{red}{+1}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claim isn't true.  Consider

$$\{a\} \overset{h} {\longrightarrow} \mathbb{N} \overset{g} {\longrightarrow} \{b\}$$