# Prove: if $f \circ g$ is bijective, then $f$ and $g$ are bijective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Full question:

Suppose that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are finite sets. Let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$. If $f \circ g$ is bijective, then $f$ and $g$ are bijective.

I've been stuck at this question for quite sometime now. Can anyone help me prove this question?

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc. Moreover, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Oops, I don't know what happened there. Try [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198381/266110).

Comment: @RiccardoAllegrone There are two different ways to define the composition of functions. So (f o g)(x) can be defined f(g(x)) or g(f(x)).

Comment: I have never seen $f \circ g$ to be defined otherwise than by $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ so I guess I would not recommend using the opposite convention since it would definitely confuse a lot of readers. The logic behing this definition is that the first function applied to the argument is $g$, the function closest to the argument $x$ in the expression$(f \circ g)(x)$. So if you have the expression $f_1 \circ \dots f_n (x)$, $x$ would successively go through $f_n$, $f_{n-1}$, ... , $f_1$

Comment: This is not true.  Take $X = Z = \{x\}$ and $y = \{y,z\}$.  Define $f(x) = y$, and $g(y) = g(z) = x$.  The function $g \circ f$ is bijective, but $f$ is not surjective and $g$ is not injective.  Note that I am using the usual convention $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to compose $f$ and $g$ in the general case here is $g \circ f$ so I assume you meant that $g \circ f$ is bijective.

For reminders :

$$
f : X \rightarrow Y
$$
and
$$
g : Y \rightarrow Z.
$$

$g \circ f$ is bijective so $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective.

Indeed, if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then $(g \circ f)(x_1) = (g \circ f)(x_2)$ so $x_1 = x_2$ by injectivity of $g \circ f$. And if $z \in Z$, there exists by surjectivity of $(g \circ f)$ an element $x \in X$ such that $z = (g \circ f) (x) = g(f(x))$ so $z$ is the image of $y = f(x)$ by $g$.

Now since $X$ and $Z$ are finite, and there is a bijection between $X$ and $Z$, we have $|X| = |Z|$.

Moreover, $f$ is injective so $|X| \leq |Y|$ and $g$ is surjective so $|Y| \geq |Z| = |X|$.

But in the general case we will not have $|Y| = |X| = |Z|$.

Try to find a simple counter-example.

Comment: what if the intention is f o g? Would that mean that this question becomes invalid?

Comment: I you want $f \circ g$ to make sense, you have to impose $g(Y) \subset X$. If it is the case, restricting $f$ to $X' = g(Y)$  you would have $g : Y \rightarrow X'$, $f : X' \rightarrow Y$, with $f \circ g : Y \rightarrow Y$ bijective so it is the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ and $Z$ be singletons and let $Y$ have more than one element.

Then there is only one function $X\to Z$ and evidently it is a bijection.

Also it is evident that a function $X\to Y$ is not surjective and the unique function $Y\to Z$ is not injective.